# Open database saved in format 4BK

Tags: export

In order to migrate to a new software I need to export data coming from previous software. 
Previous software was called univeris and makes backup in a file called **"something.4BK"**, which seems to be format used by 
http://www.4d.com
see : 
http://kb.4d.com/assetid=4514

Does anybody know how to open and export data from this file format. Any tools or procedure, or even file format internal description is welcome.
Best regards, Nicolas

Comment: You tried to open with a zip manager? 20% of time works ;) If not, you will need a lot of reverse engineering.

Comment: Yes I already tried using 7-zip... does not work

Comment: Related discussion : http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1393468/environnements-developpement/autres-edi/4d/migration-application-4d-mysql/

Comment: Yes, the expected... If you want to recover resources inside the file, you will need to know the data structure. If you don't have the client software, you will need a lot of reverse engineering to extract the data inside.

Comment: If you have a copy of 4D you can restore the database using this: http://clearviewsys.screenstepslive.com/s/manuals/m/AdministratorsGuide/l/216430-how-to-restore-a-backup-file-from-4d-server.  You can then read the data using the 4D ODBC driver.  http://www.4d.com/support/resources/features/4dodbcdriver.html